# How can I find the submodel of an SM-G900?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-5

In `About device -> Device name` it says:

```
SM-G900
```

The model name have does not a final letter. I can´t find a SM-G900 (without final letter) firmware.  How do I find out what submodel I ahve?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where you are from, or where you bought the phone, but this list might help:

- SM-G9006V_CHN_CHN (China)
- SM-G9008V_CHN_ZM (China)
- SM-G9009D_CHN_CTC (China)
- SM-G900A_NA_ATT (AT&T)
- SM-G900D_JPN_DCM (Japan)
- SM-G900F_EUR_XX (Open Europe)
- SM-G900H_EUR_XX (Open Europe)
- SM-G900I_SEA_XSA (Asia)
- SM-G900J_JPN_KDI (Japan)
- SM-G900K_KOR_KTC (Korea)
- SM-G900L_KOR_LGC (Korea)
- SM-G900M_LA_VF (Vodafone)
- SM-G900P_NA_SPR (Sprint)
- SM-G900R4_NA_USC (US Cellular)
- SM-G900S_KOR_SKC (Korea)
- SM-G900T_NA_TMB (T-Mobile)
- SM-G900V_NA_VZW (Verizon)
- SM-G900W8_NA_BMC (BMC)

[Source](http://www.sammobile.com/2014/01/29/all-model-numbers-sm-g900-galaxy-s5-confirmed/)

Comment: I bought the phone via internet. I found the same list in many websites, but I need the equivalent firmware.

Comment: @esdebon Could you give us the actual firmware you are currently using? That way we are able to identify which version fits your current one.

Comment: You are right the firmware begin with G900AUC